# How to prevent PostgreSQL from double-quoting object names in logged statements?

Tags: postgresql, logging, escaping, double-quotes

In PostgreSQL logging, when you set `log_min_duration_statement=0`, it will log all the SQL statements. Unfortunately, it also double quotes all object names. Example:

```
2016-03-14 14:57:18 EDT 000.000.000.00 cleseb LOG:  duration: 1185.000 ms  statement: SELECT * FROM "mv_summary_per_site" "s" JOIN "v_accessible_data_per_site_for_current_user" "a" ON "s"."site_id" = "a"."site_id"
```

Is there a way to change this behaviour?

Comment: It is not PostgreSQL behave. Probably these queries going from application, and Postgres send to log original query only. Try to own query.

Comment: Thanks, you're right. After talking with the Web developer, he confirmed to me that it was the framework that was automatically double-quoting the names.